# PHP timeouts while connecting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am developing chat application in PHP + Mysql.

My idea was that I open script in background(ajax) which will keep loading for a minute to check if user got any new message.

Here it is

```
    $start = time();

    while(time() - $start < 60)
    {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE `to` = '$me_user'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($result))
        {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $id = $row['id'];
        $from = $row['from'];
        $time = $row['time'];
        $msg = $row['message'];

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM messages WHERE id = $id");

        die("appendMsg('$msg',to,'$time');");
        }
    $result = null;
    Sleep(2);
    }
```

So actually it checks for new message every 2 seconds.

But my problem is that whole website starts "lagging" because of this.
I think problem is in Sleep().

Sometimes even PHP timeouts while trying to connect to DB.

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\chatly\config.php on line 19

Any suggestion how could I pause for 2 seconds?
Or you think it would be better to send new request each 2 seconds via ajax?

Comment: why don't you try to make it with ajax?

Comment: because I thought it will eat less resources if I have script loading for 60 seconds which will check for new message every 2s.

You think if ajax made a request each 2s would be better?

Comment: yes, the user can use that page without any lagging

Answer (score 0):

yo can try it with ajax:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        ajax_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        ajax_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    ajax_request.open('POST', 'getChatMessages.php', true);
    ajax_request.send(null);

    ajax_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax_request.readyState == 4) {
            if(ajax_request.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('chat_content').innerHTML = ajax_request.response;
            }
        }
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I know but I think too many requests would take too many resources.So I thought it would be better to make request only once per minute

Comment: it's the same thing, using same php or using another file, what you avoid by using ajax is the page lag

Answer (score 0):

To fix that Fatal Error you can use `ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);` to set the timeout to a minute.

The `Sleep(2)` function should be `sleep(2)`

Comment: my max_execution time is set at 60 seconds.Other parts of the script which should load instantly timeout

Comment: The PHP timeout is not set to 60 seconds. Only your while loop timeout. PHP will timeout the whole script before the while loop ends which causes the Fatal Error.

Comment: I set it like that set_time_limit(60);
I was talking about parts of the site which should load INSTANTLY but they dont because of sleep. Config.php should connect to DB instantly!